# jQuery — Fixed content with scrolling sidebar

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I need to do fixed content page and scrolling side bar. But content sometimes have height more than the browser windows. How scrolling sidebar but watch content on the left?

[image: http://i.imm.io/1elK4.png]

Comment: Right finger on the mouse wheel, eyes on the content ?

Comment: where is your trying source code?

Answer (score 1):

That is exactly what ..

[CSS Positioning](http://css-tricks.com/absolute-relative-fixed-positioining-how-do-they-differ/)

.. was created for.

Try making the content `fixed` and the right div `relative`.